# How to merge/join dataframes in R conditionally to dynamic time intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

In R I have two data frames representing covid-19 patients and I would like to merge them into one table to be able to perform the desired analyses.

df1 contains metadata of each hospital stay

df2 contains observational data for different timepoints during each stay, usually one per day but for some there are more than one per day

some cases have multiple stays and I find it difficult to merge these datasets so that the observational data is assigned to its resepctive metadata from the corresponding stay where there is no variable to indicate which stay the observational data belongs to other than the dates

Sample data can be generated with this code

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5), in_date=c("2020-03-09", "2020-02-15" , "2020-04-16" , "2020-04-19", "2020-04-24", "2020-03-01" , "2020-03-15" , "2020-05-05") , location=c("a", "a" , "a", "b" , "b" , "a", "a" ,"a" ) )
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5) , obs_time=c(
    "2020-03-09 01:00" , "2020-03-09 10:00" , "2020-03-10 05:00", 
    "2020-02-15 08:00" , "2020-02-16 09:00" , "2020-02-17 08:00", 
    "2020-04-16 14:30",  "2020-04-16 07:30" , "2020-04-17 15:00" , "2020-04-25 07:20" ,
    "2020-04-18 10:00" , "2020-04-19 10:30",  "2020-04-20 12:00", "2020-04-21 12:00" , 
    "2020-04-22 09:30" , "2020-04-24 23:00", "2020-04-23 17:30",
    "2020-03-01 08:00" , "2020-03-02 08:00" , "2020-03-03 08:00" ,  "2020-03-15 16:45" ,
     "2020-03-16 08:00" ,  "2020-05-05 13:45" , "2020-05-06 08:00" , "2020-05-07 11:00") ,
    temp_celsius=runif(25, min=35.8, max=42.0)      )
```

lubridate ymd_hm and ymd functions was used to convert the factors with dates into POSIX date-variables.

Be aware data is not completely sorted and case id 3 has 3 stays but they are all consecutive with no days between and at first day there is 2 observations. Case 4 has two stays but there are days between.

When merging the two data frames I need to assign the different observations to the different stays so that I can make plots with starting point (time zero) the time when they came in at the actual stay. In example plot the development of temprature along x axis for all cases by location group where first obs_time is time zero.

Alltough I find other threads related it is not the same.

The desired output would be like this:

```
   id         obs_time temp_celsius stay_id stay_day location
1   1 2020-03-09 01:00     40.53805       1        1        a
2   1 2020-03-09 10:00     37.54832       1        1        a
3   1 2020-03-10 05:00     38.78600       1        2        a
4   2 2020-02-15 08:00     36.19048       1        1        a
5   2 2020-02-16 09:00     37.74323       1        2        a
6   2 2020-02-17 08:00     41.83050       1        3        a
7   3 2020-04-16 14:30     39.82978       1        1        a
8   3 2020-04-16 07:30     39.84554       1        1        a
9   3 2020-04-17 15:00     38.31164       1        2        a
10  3 2020-04-25 07:20     36.37992       3        2        b
11  3 2020-04-18 10:00     38.65261       1        3        a
12  3 2020-04-19 10:30     38.94991       2        1        b
13  3 2020-04-20 12:00     36.84384       2        2        b
14  3 2020-04-21 12:00     35.81786       2        3        b
15  3 2020-04-22 09:30     39.20979       2        4        b
16  3 2020-04-24 23:00     41.39876       3        1        b
17  3 2020-04-23 17:30     37.68251       2        5        b
18  4 2020-03-01 08:00     41.55690       1        1        a
19  4 2020-03-02 08:00     38.53060       1        2        a
20  4 2020-03-03 08:00     39.99385       1        3        a
21  4 2020-03-15 16:45     38.29500       2        1        a
22  4 2020-03-16 08:00     41.20947       2        2        a
23  5 2020-05-05 13:45     36.43556       1        1        a
24  5 2020-05-06 08:00     41.06712       1        2        a
25  5 2020-05-07 11:00     36.76612       1        3        a
```

Hope anyone can help me with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this just about covers it. Rolling joins from `data.table` and a little manipulation should get you there.

```r
set.seed(1)

library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5),
                  in_date=c("2020-03-09", "2020-02-15" , "2020-04-16" , "2020-04-19", "2020-04-24", "2020-03-01" , "2020-03-15" , "2020-05-05") ,
                  location=c("a", "a" , "a", "b" , "b" , "a", "a" ,"a" ) )
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5) , obs_time=c(
  "2020-03-09 01:00" , "2020-03-09 10:00" , "2020-03-10 05:00", 
  "2020-02-15 08:00" , "2020-02-16 09:00" , "2020-02-17 08:00", 
  "2020-04-16 14:30",  "2020-04-16 07:30" , "2020-04-17 15:00" , "2020-04-25 07:20" ,
  "2020-04-18 10:00" , "2020-04-19 10:30",  "2020-04-20 12:00", "2020-04-21 12:00" , 
  "2020-04-22 09:30" , "2020-04-24 23:00", "2020-04-23 17:30",
  "2020-03-01 08:00" , "2020-03-02 08:00" , "2020-03-03 08:00" ,  "2020-03-15 16:45" ,
  "2020-03-16 08:00" ,  "2020-05-05 13:45" , "2020-05-06 08:00" , "2020-05-07 11:00") ,
  temp_celsius=runif(25, min=35.8, max=42.0))

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[, c('in_date') := .(lubridate::ymd(in_date))]
df1[, stay_id := 1:.N, by = id]
df2[, obs_time := lubridate::ymd_hm(obs_time)]
df2[, obs_date := as.Date(obs_time)]

df1[df2, .(id, in_date, obs_time, temp_celsius, stay_id, location), on = c('id', 'in_date' = 'obs_date'), roll = Inf][
  , stay_day := as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(obs_time), min(as.Date(in_date)), units = 'day')) + 1, by = .(id, stay_id)][, in_date := NULL][]
#>     id            obs_time temp_celsius stay_id location stay_day
#>  1:  1 2020-03-09 01:00:00     37.44615       1        a        1
#>  2:  1 2020-03-09 10:00:00     38.10717       1        a        1
#>  3:  1 2020-03-10 05:00:00     39.35169       1        a        2
#>  4:  2 2020-02-15 08:00:00     41.43089       1        a        1
#>  5:  2 2020-02-16 09:00:00     37.05043       1        a        2
#>  6:  2 2020-02-17 08:00:00     41.37002       1        a        3
#>  7:  3 2020-04-16 14:30:00     41.65699       1        a        1
#>  8:  3 2020-04-16 07:30:00     39.89695       1        a        1
#>  9:  3 2020-04-17 15:00:00     39.70051       1        a        2
#> 10:  3 2020-04-25 07:20:00     36.18307       3        b        2
#> 11:  3 2020-04-18 10:00:00     37.07704       1        a        3
#> 12:  3 2020-04-19 10:30:00     36.89465       2        b        1
#> 13:  3 2020-04-20 12:00:00     40.05954       2        b        2
#> 14:  3 2020-04-21 12:00:00     38.18144       2        b        3
#> 15:  3 2020-04-22 09:30:00     40.57302       2        b        4
#> 16:  3 2020-04-24 23:00:00     38.88574       3        b        1
#> 17:  3 2020-04-23 17:30:00     40.24923       2        b        5
#> 18:  4 2020-03-01 08:00:00     41.94982       1        a        1
#> 19:  4 2020-03-02 08:00:00     38.15622       1        a        2
#> 20:  4 2020-03-03 08:00:00     40.62016       1        a        3
#> 21:  4 2020-03-15 16:45:00     41.59517       2        a        1
#> 22:  4 2020-03-16 08:00:00     37.11528       2        a        2
#> 23:  5 2020-05-05 13:45:00     39.84038       1        a        1
#> 24:  5 2020-05-06 08:00:00     36.57844       1        a        2
#> 25:  5 2020-05-07 11:00:00     37.45677       1        a        3
#>     id            obs_time temp_celsius stay_id location stay_day
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot zack ! I am always impressed by the skills of professionals :)